# Using method in System.out wont work?

Tags: java

I am tasked with several objectives in my assignment, I am to read a file, which i believe I did correctly, and from that file of integers, put it into an array.  It wont let me compile the code, it comes up with an error at smallest.  So, how do I printout the method of the min?

```
public class jlrogers2 {

public static void reader(int[] arr) throws FileNotFoundException { 

 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("numbers.txt"));
    int i = 0;

    while(scanner.hasNextInt())
    {
        arr[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
    }


}

public static int minnimum(int[] arr){

int smallest =arr[0];

for (int i = 1; i>arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i] > smallest)
        {
            smallest= arr[i];
            System.out.println(smallest);
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
 public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException   
{  


    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for max index value.\nEnter 2 for min index   value.\nEnter 3 to search for an index value.\n"
            + "Enter 4 for display all index's\nEnter 5 for numbers in a range.\nEnter 6 to exit menu. ");

    int number = in.nextInt();

    if(number==6){
        System.out.println("Thank you for being awesome");
    }

    if (number==5){
    System.out.println(minnimum(smallest))  // here is my issue }


}
```

}

Comment: "Obviously, I am doing something wrong" unfortunately isn't a very helpful description of your problem. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I listed it in the tag.  When I attempt  System.out.println(minimum(smallest); it doesnt work, so essientally i cannot figure out why I am getting an error when I try to print that method

Comment: minimum function takes an array as an argument,not an integer.. Moreover you are not calling **reader()**  method and *smallest* is not defined in main

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `for (int i = 1; i>arr.length; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)`
And also your logic to find smallest is wrong. Actually you are finding the largest.

To find smallest put it as

`if(arr[i] < smallest )` inside `for` loop

Change the main as

```
 public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException   
{  

 Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter 1 for max index value.\nEnter 2 for min index   value.\nEnter 3 to search for an index value.\n"
        + "Enter 4 for display all index's\nEnter 5 for numbers in a range.\nEnter 6 to exit menu. ");

 int number = in.nextInt();
 int arr[] = new int [200];//change this according to the requirement
 if(number==6){
    System.out.println("Thank you for being awesome");
}

if (number==5){
  reader(arr); 
 System.out.println(minnimum(arr)); 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be many problems with your code:-

->First as others have pointed change `for (int i = 1; i>arr.length; i++)` to `for (int i = 1; i<arr.length; i++)`

-> variable `int smallest` used, is not a class level variable and also is never locally declared in `main()`

-> method `minimum()` is never called from main, also method `reader()` seems to be not called

-> close the scanners after use, call `scanner.close()` at method end

Make some changes hence:-

-> `main()` would now look like:-

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException   
{  
    int[] arr=new int[100];
    reader(arr);//call this to populate arr[]
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for max index value.\nEnter 2 for min index   value.\nEnter 3 to search for an index value.\n"
            + "Enter 4 for display all index's\nEnter 5 for numbers in a range.\nEnter 6 to exit menu. ");

    int number = in.nextInt();

    if(number==6){
        System.out.println("Thank you for being awesome");
    }

    if (number==5){
        System.out.println(minnimum(arr));
    }

   in.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH!  One final question, I did everything you pointed out, but when I added static int arr[]=new arr[100]; , I receive and error asking me to change it.  I attempted editing it, but everything I do comes back with an error

Comment: oops i made a typo, change it to `static int[] arr=new int[100];`

Comment: I have made some updates to make less changes in your source, and stick with passing array as parameter. You can refer this answer now

Answer (score 0):

To find smallest element you need to change your loop like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) 
{
      if (arr[i] < smallest)
      {
        smallest = arr[i];
      }
}
```